# Ubuntu does not work due to Buffer I/0 error

Tags: initramfs, busybox

After turning my laptop on, it did not work normally and not show ubuntu loading page instead it showed a prompted line (initramfs) and asked me to insert any command,I tried ls and found it does not show home directory. Apparently, there is an ubuntu on it but not working properly, should I install a new one?
Are my whole data on home directory are deleted?
Another things on this page are about needing manual fsck on dev/sda2, busybox v1.30.1 built-in shell, and buffer I/0 error on dev sda2

Comment: Were any changes made in the last session? was it shutdown cleanly? I would consider that (you gave no details).. but if that gave nothing, I'd boot *live* media (eg. Ubuntu installation media and use the "*Try Ubuntu*") and file-system check (`fsck` or use a GUI tool to do it) your partition(s).   If errors are found & corrected, I'd just reboot (removing *live* media), and expect to boot and login normally....

Comment: Thanks, I shut it down manually with power button. My system frozen before this, and when I restarted it, I faced with this page. I will try your solution.

Comment: Shutting down with the power button is not a clean shutdown; did keyboard commands not allow a clean shutdown (even if your GUI is frozen, no mouse movement etc), SysRq commands allow you to direct the kernel to shutdown (will work unless kernel has panic'd which you can usually see by panic text messages on display replacing any GUI display).   If you don't know them, a quick search for "magic sysrq" on a phone will show the wikipedia page which is as good as any... to let you tell your box to REISUB (B=reBoot) or REISUO (O=power Off) both of which are safer than cutting power!

Comment: At the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda2` or `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda2`. Then type `reboot` or `exit` then `reboot`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Many thanks, that works! And thank you for telling me those commands, I will use them in the future if it repeats again.